# Call an action when closing a JSP

Tags: java, jsp

I'm new to the java web world, so forgive me if I say something stupid.

I'm working with struts 2 and I need to delete a file (which is located on the server) when a jsp is closed.

Does any body knows how to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `window.onunload` suggestion is nice, but there is no guarantee that the ajax request will ever hit the server. As far as I recall, only certain IE versions with certain configurations will send the ajax request successfully. Firefox and others won't do that. And then I don't talk about the cases when the user has JS disabled.

You don't want to rely on that. Rather hook on the session expiration. You can do that with help of [`HttpSessionListener`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html) or maybe [`HttpSessionBindingListener`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionBindingListener.html) when it concerns an (existing) attribute of the session.

E.g.

```
public class CleanupSession implements HttpSessionListener {

    @Override
    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent event) {
        new File(somePath).delete();
    }

    // ...
}
```

(register it in `web.xml` as a `<listener>`)

Or, in case of an "logged-in user" example (which is stored in the session scope):

```
public void User implements HttpSessionBindingListener {

    @Override
    public void valueUnbound(HttpSessionBindingEvent event) {
        new File(somePath).delete();
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. Keep in mind that the session will not be immediately expred when the browser window/tab is closed. It'll last by default 30 minutes thereafter. But it's at least the most robust way to ensure the file being deleted.

Comment: The file I need to delete depends of the user, and since I have to define a new class I'm having problems telling the method what file delete.

Comment: You could make it a property of the `User` class. The `User` class should of course represent the logged-in user. All with all, you basically need to store a reference to the `File` (in)directly in the session.

Answer (score 2):

On [`window.onunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onunload) call, using ajax, an action that deletes the file.