# Practical Usage of HttpSessionBindingListener And HttpSessionAttributeListener

Tags: session, servlets, listener

I am reading through head first JSP and servlets. Going through different type of listeners, I came across `HttpSessionBindingListener` and `HttpSessionAttributeListener`.

I was thinking about the difference between the two - I want to see the practical usages in real world examples of those two listeners. I tested `HttpSessionBindingListener` by implementing `valueBound()` and `valueUnBound()` - why would an object need to know whether it has been added or not?

I am pretty confused about the practical usages. Please help in clarifying this.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The [`HttpSessionBindingListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionBindingListener.html) is to be implemented on the class whose instances may be stored in the session, such as the logged-in user.

E.g.

```
public class ActiveUser implements HttpSessionBindingListener {

    @Override
    public void valueBound(HttpSessionBindingEvent event) {
        logins.add(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void valueUnbound(HttpSessionBindingEvent event) {
        logins.remove(this);
    }

}
```

When an instance of this `ActiveUser` get set as a session attribute by `HttpSession#setAttribute()`, then the `valueBound()` will be invoked. When it get removed by either `HttpSession#removeAttribute()`, or an invalidate of the session, or get replaced by another `HttpSession#setAttribute()`, then the `valueUnbound()` will be invoked.

Here are some real world use cases:

- [Getting SessionScoped bean from HttpSessionListener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5239103/getting-sessionscoped-bean-from-httpsessionlistener/)
- [How to call a method before the session object is destroyed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7756054/how-to-call-a-method-before-the-session-object-is-destroyed/)
- [Call an action when closing a JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3409569/call-an-action-when-closing-a-jsp/)
- [implementing HttpSessionListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5259764/implementing-httpsessionlistener/)
- [How to access HTTP sessions in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3235997/how-to-access-http-sessions-in-java/)

The [`HttpSessionAttributeListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionAttributeListener.html) is to be implemented as an application wide `@WebListener` which get invoked when **any** attribute is added, removed or replaced in the `HttpSession`. Continuing with the above `ActiveUser` example, this is particularly useful if you can't modify the `ActiveUser` class to implement `HttpSessionBindingListener` (because it's 3rd party or so), or when you want to make use of a "marker interface" on an arbitrary amount of classes so that you can do the listening job in a single central place.

```
@WebListener
public class ActiveUserListener implements HttpSessionAttributeListener {

    @Override
    public void attributeAdded(HttpSessionBindingEvent event) {
        if (event.getValue() instanceof ActiveUser) {
            logins.add(event.getValue());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void attributeRemoved(HttpSessionBindingEvent event) {
        if (event.getValue() instanceof ActiveUser) {
            logins.remove(event.getValue());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void attributeReplaced(HttpSessionBindingEvent event) {
        if (event.getValue() instanceof ActiveUser) {
            logins.add(event.getValue());
        }
    }

}
```

Here's a real world use case:

- [Getting notification when bounded/unbounded to a HTTP session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11258724/getting-notification-when-bounded-unbounded-to-a-http-session/)

Comment: Thanks so much @BalusC. I understood the difference. Thanks so much for the detailed answer.

Comment: This is a great answer. @BalusC how do you manage to get this all information and present in such nice way.

Comment: @BalusC - my book explains Http session binding with real world example. It say - Consider a `Customer` class, with each active instance representing a single customer's info for name, address, order info, etc. The real data is stored in an underlying database. You use the database to populate the fields of a Customer object. The `HttpSessionBindingListener` methods help you to keep the Object in sync with the database and vice versa.

Comment: @BalusC - So, if the Customer logins into his e-shopping account info page, will there be some kind of `javascript/js` `Object` which will load all this info from db to prevent repeated DB hits ? When a user edits his home address, then the object will be used to update the database ?