# session listener - valueBound or valueUnbound doesn't called

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets, httpsession

I've just tried to add session listeners in my test web app the [HttpSessionBindingListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionBindingListener.html) and [HttpSessionAttributeListener](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionAttributeListener.html) ones; 
They both implemented into my test object as :

```
public class MySessionListener implements HttpSessionBindingListener,HttpSessionAttributeListener 
{
//implemented methods...
}
```

The thing is...

I tried code like a

```
session.setAttribute("name",new TestValue());
```

as a result, I expected to call `HttpSessionBindingListener` event like `valueBound(...)` but I have called just the `HttpSessionAttributeListener` one as `attributeAdded(...)` only :(

Moreover, concerning the `valueUnbound(...)` method attitude is totally the same thing as I mentioned for I use code like

```
session.removeAttribute("name");
```

...but I get all the same `attributeRemoved(...)` being called only :S

I wanted to try [putValue()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#putValue%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29) method instead but right now I am watching HttpSession docs which says that "putValue is Deprecated. As of Version 2.2, this method is replaced by setAttribute(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object)"

So I don't get it why the `valueBound(...)` or `valueUnbound(...)` doesn't invoke and how to invoke them anyway?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Short answer

valueBound is not being called because `MySessionListener` is not the object being added to a session.

If `TestValue` implemented `HttpSessionBindingListener` it's `valueBound` method would be called.

### Longer Explanation

`HttpSessionBindingListener` is used to notify the object that it is being added to a session.

`HttpSessionAttributeListener` is used (as you discovered) for attributes being added/removed from a session.

With the `HttpSessionBindingListener` here is what the container is saying: "Hey `TestValue`, you were added to a session"

With the `HttpSessionAttributeListener` here is what the container is saying: "Hey MySessionListener, an attribute was added to a session"

So, if `TestValue` implements `HttpSessionBindingListener`, it would have valueBound called when added to a session:

```
session.setAttribute("name",new TestValue());
```

In your case, if you added an instance of `MySessionListener` to a session (not that you'd want to, but because it implements `HttpSessionBindingListener`) it would call the `valueBound` method when added to a session:

```
session.setAttribute("name", new MySessionListener());
```

Also see: [Practical Usage of HttpSessionBindingListener And HttpSessionAttributeListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17776704/practical-usage-of-httpsessionbindinglistener-and-httpsessionattributelistener)

Comment: Thanks. But as for my case I don't get it "how to add directly to session itself" because I cannot see (in its docs - http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html) any related "add" method except the addAttribute(...) one :S You mean the putValue(...,...) method which is deprecated?

Comment: setAttribute will trigger valueBound, removeAttribute (or expiration of the session) will trigger valueUnbound.

Comment: "Will trigger" ? What you mean? You mean they are chained and synchronized or something? Give more details please because I don't get it should I use putValue(...,...) instead of setAttribute(...,...)

Comment: By "Will trigger", I mean "will cause" because by implementing that interface it is the containers job to notify the object.  putValue (as you indicated) is deprecated so you should use setAttribute which will add the object to the session.

Comment: Yeah. So I did. But I have HttpSessionAttributeListener methods working only :( But why?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to implement both interfaces on one object - do you understand the difference between the two interfaces (one is for the object being added, the other is for an external listener)?  If you want valueBound to be called, it has to be the object that is being bound to the session.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39005/discussion-between-amir-t-and-user592704)